# How does cURL decide which when to reuse a connection?

Tags: curl

The cURL library has a [couple options](http://www.scriptbasic.com/html/texi/mod_curl.html#3.45.) called `FRESH_CONNECT` and `FORBID_REUSE` that help with special requests such as `POST` where responses often should not be stored.

However, I want to know if curl is smart enough to know a post/delete/put request with parameters should not be cached - *or if these parameters must be explicitly set*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options are related to the reuse of connections, not requests or responses. You can safely reuse a connection for multiple requests.

Comment: Ok, so the response isn't cached - just the connection object? So I can make a make a SSL followed by a HTTP request without worries?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Just the connection is reused. It's called HTTP Keep-Alive (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).